# AngularJS Directive - Passing function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

When writing AngularJS Directive with Isolate Scope,
Is it bad practice to pass a function with "=" instead of "&"?

```
scope: {
        myFunc: '&'
    },
```

or

```
scope: {
        myFunc: '='
    },
```

[equal-sign](https://jsfiddle.net/lotyu/pxwaa0x4/) vs [ampersand](http://jsfiddle.net/lotyu/g4kwybns/)

Comment: What do you mean by `Is it bad practice`? Why would you want to pass it using `=`?

Comment: @AlonEitan I want to avoid calling my function inside the directive with double parenthesis. myFunc("123") instead of myFunc()("123").